# Create model for schema of csv file

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I need to create model for schema which consists of name and columns. Users can build the data schema with any number of columns of any type. Each column also has its own name (which will be a column header in the CSV file), type and order (just a number to manage column order).

The problem is that I have to create schema at one time with columns, but I don't know how to do this.

My current models:

```
SCHEMA_TYPE_CHOICE = (
    ('Full Name', 'Full Name'),
    ('Job', 'Job'),
    ('Email', 'Email'),
    ('Company', 'Company'),
    ('Phone Number', 'Phone Number'),
    ('Address', 'Address'),
    ('Date', 'Date'),
)


class Schema(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Column(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SCHEMA_TYPE_CHOICE, default='Full Name')
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    schema = models.ForeignKey(Schema, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='column_schema')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Form that I have to realize:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvsxW.png)

Comment: please clarify "The problem is that I have to create schema at one time with columns, but I don't know how to do this."

Comment: As you can see on screenshot of form, user should enter schema name, create n-amount of columns and then save it all with button submit. I don't know how to buid relationship between schema and its columns

Comment: It looks like you already have a foreign key relationship, so that relationship should be good to go, I don't understand the question

Comment: When user adds new columns, its schema doesn't exist so that I can not fill the field schema in column's model, cause schema wasn't created yet.

Comment: I think my models is not correct

Comment: then you need to create the schema object before or while they're filling out the form